# On hover OwlCarousel how to show the nav?

Tags: jquery, css, owl-carousel

I'm trying to get the nav to show only when the carousel is hovered but not sure how to approach this. Should I be using a visibility toggle?

*EDIT*

[image]

http://jsfiddle.net/TWtwt/470/

```
.owl-theme .owl-controls .owl-nav [class*=owl-] {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-family: 'KeplerStd-Regular';
  display: block;
  cursor: e-resize;
}

.owl-theme .owl-controls .owl-nav [class*=owl-]:hover {
  background-color: #1f1f1f;
  transition: 0.5s all;
  cursor: e-resize
}
```

Comment: try this : http://jsfiddle.net/DinoMyte/TWtwt/471/

Comment: @DinoMyte I still see the nav though even when the mouse isn't hovered ontop of the carousel.

Comment: try this : http://jsfiddle.net/DinoMyte/TWtwt/472/

Comment: @DinoMyte Maybe I'm not making myself clear enough. I added a pic to OP to hopefully clear it up. Here is an example of when you hover a carousel and the nav appears. http://andrewgooch.com/year-of-svu-franchise

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to change the opacity of `owl-prev` and `owl-next` to 0 in your CSS code, like this:

```
.owl-prev, .owl-next {opacity: 0 !important;}
```

Then, you can define `hover` action on `owl-carousel` to show/hide it as follows:

```
.owl-carousel:hover .owl-controls .owl-buttons .owl-prev {opacity: 1 !important;}
.owl-carousel:hover .owl-controls .owl-buttons .owl-next {opacity: 1 !important;}
```

Check out working example [HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/ywykje7e/)